# How to extract plain text from mediawiki?

Tags: python, mediawiki

I have exported some categories from https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Special:Export. <del>They come in XML format.</del> I would like plain text from the "Synopsis" sections. You can download the whole thing [here](https://easyupload.io/do8jbt) (54KB compressed).

A typical Synopsis section looks like:

> ==Synopsis== [[Catelyn Tully|Catelyn]] listens to the continuous pounding noise of the drums the musicians in the hall are playing. She
> is seated between [[Ryman Frey]] and [[Roose Bolton]] during the
> wedding feast. She remarks to herself how joyless the wedding is, and
> watches as [[Robb Stark|Robb]] dances with several of the Frey maids
> and [[Edmure Tully|Edmure]] dotes on his soon to be wife, [[Roslin
> Frey|Roslin]]. Catelyn becomes more wary when she learns that [[Olyvar
> Frey|Olyvar]], [[Perwyn Frey|Perwyn]], and [[Alesander Frey]] are all
> not in attendance at the wedding. She notices [[Merrett Frey]] trying
> to drink the [[Greatjon Umber|Greatjon]] under the table, and finally
> Lord [[Walder Frey]] calls for the bedding. Robb does not participate
> as the Greatjon carries a weeping Roslin to the bed chamber.

How can I extract the plain text from all the Synopsis sections?

Comment: This isn't XML ... Looks like RST, which really is plaintext with some links thrown in

Comment: Assuming you had XHTML, then https://lxml.de/tutorial.html

Comment: @OneCricketeer Interesting. The linked page says "You can export the text and editing history of a particular page or set of pages wrapped in some XML." . I don't know much about XML myself. I just want the plaintext.

Comment: Plenty of examples if you just search what it looks like... What you pasted is already plaintext, so I'm not understanding the question

Comment: @OneCricketeer I would like the plain  text (so [[Catelyn Tully|Catelyn]] becomes Catelyn Tully for example) from the Synopsis sections. There are too many to copy and edit by hand.

Comment: Use regex for that to find patterns of `[[text|link]]` and replace with just `text`... Not sure why you're calling that "XML" when you say you dont know XML

Comment: Not in a place wtere I can properly examine the download link, but it looks like the ReST is wrapped in some XML. To do this properly, you'd have to first unwrap the XML scaffolding (probably something fairly simple like `<xml><metadata .../><actualdata>Your ReST content here</actualdata></xml>`) and then apply a ReST parser to the extracted data ... But if your needs are simple, maybe just write your own regex to pull out the Synopsis sections and remove square bracket links.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/12883428/407651. I think the question is a bit lazy (shows no real research effort), but the markup in the question is not reStructuredText. It is MediaWiki markup. The linked file ("the whole thing") is indeed an XML file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279589/ doesn't contain any good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to parse it as XML. I recommend using lxml and xpath.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('file.xml')
expression = '/m:mediawiki/m:page/m:revision/m:text/text()'
namespaces = {"m": "http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/"}
texts = tree.xpath(expression, namespaces=namespaces)
```

Once you get all text portions, use a regular expression to parse them one by one. Or write your own parser.

Comment: If the input really was XML, find an existing question with a similar answer, and close as duplicate. At 50k rep you should no longer need to answer questions just for the rep. But in addition, the inpqt very clearly isn't actually XML.

Comment: @tripleee Are you sure the full file I linked isn't XML?